# How to vertically and horizontally center a square SVG in CSS such that only the image is visible in the viewport no matter it dimensions

Tags: html, image, css, svg, centering

I am trying to take an SVG and display it on mobile and desktop browsers. The SVG is *square*, so if I just try centering it vertically and horizontally using `contain` it will show the square image in the center. That's not what I want.

What I want is to have it center on the image, and *zoom in* on it so that all you see is *part* of the image and the rest is clipped by the viewport. I can't upload images to show you, but this drawing should help clarify.

**Mobile**:

```
  ┌┄┄┄┄╔═══════╗┄┄┄┄┐
  ┆    ║       ║    ┆
  ┆    ║       ║    ┆
  ┆    ║       ║    ┆
  ┆    ║       ║    ┆
  ┆    ║       ║    ┆
  ┆    ║       ║    ┆
  └┄┄┄┄╚═══════╝┄┄┄┄┘
        ^           ^
        |           |
  viewport          image
```

**Desktop**:

```
                image
                |
                v
       ┌┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┐
       ╔═════════════════╗
       ║                 ║    
       ║                 ║    
       ║                 ║    
       ║                 ║<-- viewport
       ║                 ║    
       ║                 ║    
       ╚═════════════════╝
       └┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┘
```

I tried `object-fit: cover` but no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
yourSelector {
  background: url('path/to/your/svg') center /cover;
}
```

...should do it.
In the shorthand above, `/cover` is short for

```
background-size: cover;
```

See it working:

```css
div {
  background: url('https://placeholder.pics/svg/300') center /cover;
}
.one{
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
}
.two {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}
.three {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100px;
}
.four {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
<div class="four"></div>
```

Or as `background-image` of `<body>`:

```css
body {
  background: url('https://placeholder.pics/svg/300') center /cover;
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Comment: What if the SVG is inline HTML, i.e. you can't use `background: url(...)`. How to do it then.

Comment: Use `background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg>...</svg>') center /cover;` However, it is best to encode your `<svg>` in base64 using an online tool. (i.e.: https://www.base64encode.org/). Obviously, you need to change encoding from `utf8` to `base64` if you do. There are a good number of sites where you simply paste your `<svg>` code and they give you the exact `background-image` to use in return.

Comment: In all fairness, `utf8` works perfectly fine if your `<svg>` doesn't contain the delimiter character. If you use single quotes as delimiters, like I did above, make sure `<svg>` only contains double quotes or vice-versa.